# Auto update asp.net web application from remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-deployment, auto-update

I have several clients who are using web application hosted in their local IIS server at different locations. Currently all are using version 1.0.

I published the new version of the application say version 1.1, zipped and host in http server at location X.

My application can check if new version is available or not. Now what can be done so that v1.0 at client side can be replaced with new version i.e. 1.1. I want the v1.0 running at client side, automatically (of course with user permission) downloads the v1.1 from http server using internet, extracts the file and host itself in local IIS server.

Is their any method like **ClickOnce** for web application? I have build the application using asp.net C#. Any 3rd party application or C# code sample would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

I came across your question, if you want to make web apps that are self updating, you can check a solution here http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/15/building-a-self-updating-site-using-nuget.aspx/, as for updating database, you can add a bootsrapper class that if you are using nHibernate use SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(true, true); that you call on site/index to ensure that the schema is updating. hope thats help